# Перезагрузка страницы с помощью ссылки

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь сделать кнопку "Очистить все", при нажатии на которую будет происходить тоже самое, что и при нажатии на кнопку F5, но ничего не работает... Подскажите, в чем ошибка? Я понимаю, что так лучше не делать (не мешать JS и HTML), но пока что даже так не работает!

```
<a href="#" title="Очистить все" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="refresh()">Очистить все</a>

function refresh()
    {
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

Comment: А вы что именно отчищете? Данные форм?

Comment: Да, данные форм и элемент CANVAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="reset" value="Очистить" />
```

Или как вариант:

```
<a href="#" title="Очистить все" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.reload();">Очистить все</a>.
```

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит, так как он очищает только то, что написано в формах, а то что нарисовано в элементе canvas остается, но все равно огромное спасибо за попытку помочь!

Comment: Вам надо сброс? А если сделать так:
`<a href="#" title="Очистить все" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="refresh();">Очистить все</a>` Может ваша функция оживет?

Comment: не хочет оживать(((

Пробывал:

onclick="refresh();"
onclick="refresh()"
onclick="refresh(); return false;"

Не хочет работать и все... Это ппц... Я не знаю, что делать! Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: onclick="window.location.href='ссылка на какой находитесь'"

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант, но пока что я делаю на localhost'e

Comment: А если так?

    <a href="#" title="Очистить все" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.reload();">Очистить все</a>